# How to find the dynamical equations of a two body problem ?

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

Consider 2 stars with positions r1,r2 and masses m1, m2 which interact via their mutual gravitational attraction. What are the dynamical equations for $ \vec r_{1} $ and $ \vec r_{2} $ ? The answer in the solutions is $ m_{1}r''_{1} = -G_{N}m_{1}m_{2} \vec r_{1}-\vec r_{2}/|\vec r_{1} -r_{2}|^3    $ and similarly for m2. I can see that the equation has been derived using $ F=- \nabla V $ but I am really unsure of where the terms come from particularly the term in the denominator.

Comment: Gravitational pull is inversely proportional to the squared distance (since classical mechanics works in a 3D Euclidean geometry), call it 1/d², and the force is directed towards the second body, so **d** /d gives us the direction (a unity vector). Hence **d** /d³. Bolds are vectors.

Comment: Re your previous questions, are you aware of the concept of **accepting** an answer?